# How can I concatenate text in one row?

Tags: sql, bash, concatenation, string-concatenation, mariadb-10.4

I'am using MariaDB and I can do this:

```
`SELECT file_target FROM oc_share WHERE uid_initiator = 'aaa329';

+--------------------------------+
| file_target                    |
+--------------------------------+
| /2012                          |
| /ownCloud Manual 1 2 3 4 5.pdf |
+--------------------------------+
```

or this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(file_target) FROM oc_share WHERE uid_initiator = 'aaa329';

+--------------------------------+
| CONCAT(file_target)            |
+--------------------------------+
| /2012                          |
| /ownCloud Manual 1 2 3 4 5.pdf |
+--------------------------------+
```

so far so easy..., but if I then want to process the result further, the row with the text '/ownCloud Manual 1 2 3 4 5.pdf' is not seen as a continuous string because there are spaces here.

Now my question: How can I get the text into a single string? With a SQL-statement or with bash script?

This is an excerpt from a test bash script:

```
local Shares=$(mysql -sN -P "${DBPORT}" --host="${DBHOST}" --user="${DBUSER}" --password="${DBPASS}" -e "${SharesCMD}" "${DBNAME}")         
local sharesArray=(${Shares})         
for index in "${!sharesArray[@]}"
do
   echo "$index ${sharesArray[index]}"
done
```

My output:

```
0 /2012 
1 /ownCloud 
2 Manual 
3 1 
4 2 
5 3 
6 4 
7 5.pdf
```

I would like to have:

```
0 /2012 
1 /ownCloud Manual 1 2 3 4 5.pdf
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: looking for `group_concat()?` https://mariadb.com/kb/en/group_concat/

Comment: Set `IFS=$'\n'` before creating the array so that it will use newline as the delimiter, not any whitespace.

Comment: Isn't your expected output supposed to be on multiple lines?

Comment: Thank you Barmar. Set IFS=$'\n' was the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you do

```
local sharesArray=(${Shares})
```

it splits the variable at whitespace by default, so all the words in `/ownCloud Manual 1 2 3 4 5.pdf` become separate array elements.

You can use the `IFS` variable to control how this is split.

```
IFS=$'\n'
local sharesArray=(${Shares})
```